# Gyro - Determine angle accuracy from datasheet

Tags: gyroscope

I have a few Gyro's that I am considering for a new project that needs accurate positioning on moving parts.

What I don't fully understand is how to pick a Gyro that will report back an accurate enough angle.

Take for example and MPU-6050, how do I work out how accurate it will be at calculating angels before I go out an buy the unit.

Datasheet : https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General%20IC/PS-MPU-6000A.pdf

More Details:
The machine I'm adding the interface to is a small Heliostat. It will be static and controlled by motors. The idea is to point/move it the preferred position by hand. My main concern is will the Gyro be able to provide 0.05 degree accuracy after converting/smoothing the readings to degrees.

Comment: What do you mean by "accurate"? And gyros do not report angles, they report rates.

Comment: Gyros report back change in angle, but accurate is not a word you may want to use for them. What kind of accuracy are you looking for?

Comment: @MadHatter I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - This unit does not report rates. It reports change in angle over a defined time interval.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Isn't it a definition of "rate" - change over time?

Comment: But yes, this specific unit is not a gyro, it is IMU, with integrated DMP, which can report different useful stuff.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Unless otherwise stated, "rate" usually implies instantaneous measurement, although if the sample interval is small enough total integrated change will do. For example, a change of 1 degree in a one-second interval (one degree per second) says nothing about peak rates during that interval.

Comment: You cannot control a heliostat with a gyro. Use a stepper motor (in which case you don't need position sensing) or use a rotary encoder to sense the angle. I have not done such things, but I have some experience with gyros and IMU's and there is no way they can control the pointing angle the way you want (unless you go to fairly high-end IMU's).

Comment: @mkeith. Looking at the tiny angles I agree with you. Even if this could be done with a Gyro it would be hard to accurately point those angles by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first you go to section 6.1, Gyroscope Specifications. There you will see that the zero reading can be as much as 20 degrees per second, and that it can vary as much as 20 degrees/second over the rated temperature range. If you can run a zero point reference cycle just before your measurement, you can compensate for both of those. If not, the best you can do is a calibration procedure to determine the offset for various temperatures, then measure the temperature of the unit at the time of measurement, and use that as a correction factor. Fortunately, the unit also measures temperature, so that's simple enough.

Second, you notice that scale factor has a tolerance, so you'll need to calibrate each unit if your desired accuracy is less than the tolerance. Ditto for temperature effects.

Then you notice that there is a noise specification as well, so you take that into account, usually by filtering the data to reduce total noise.

Oh yes, and depending on your requirements, you'll also need to analyze your system to determine the power supply stability, since that also affects the output.

In other words, in order to "work out how accurate it will be at calculating angels", first you need to understand the voltage and temperature behavior of your measurement system, then determine exactly how you are going to acquire and process your data. Then apply that information to the specifications in the data sheet.